# Promoting NuGet Packages to release versions

Tags: tfs, nuget, nuget-package, tfs-2015

We have several assemblies that we share over all our projects. Since last year we use NuSpec files to create packages and share them all in a internal feed. The packaging is done as part of the build process (TFS 2015). Versioning is set to automatic, use date and time. The build is a CI build and triggered when merging from the Development branch to the CI branch.

When one wants to use the packages, one has to enable "include prelease" in the NuGet Package Manager to get these packages. This is ok, for time while a package is not completely tested, but ready to release.

**Question**

What I am looking for is a straight forward way now, to promote such packages, once they've been created and tested, to a release version, leaving the original `Major.Minor.Revision` but removing the date portion of the prelease version and share that new version in a - ideally the same - feed.

Comment: What's the detail version format of your release and prelease version for now? And how you want to achieve finally? Could you explain more clearly by adding a sample.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with example. I can post a screenshot with the settings made in the "NuGet Packager" task. But you won't see anything else than I wrote above: versioning is set to automatic using date and time.